# UIRefreshControl in Landscape

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uirefreshcontrol

I've got a UIRefreshControl at the top of my table.

The screen is in landscape.

The trouble is, I can't pull down far enough in order to trigger the refresh, because there is too little space in Landscape. Is there a way to adjust the amount you have to pull down?

Comment: Very interested in discovering the root cause of this issue. Unable to reproduce in Xcode 4.5 on OS X 10.8.2

Comment: my app has a navigation bar, as well as a UISearchBar at the top of the table, so there is less room to pull

Comment: If you only have a nav bar and a search bar then fair enough, sounds like this should work as expected. The Mail app has search bar and nav bar, works fine there, what else do you have in your screen ?

Comment: how else did you achieve the effect? what property did you change

Comment: `UIRefreshControl` wasn't supported by `UIScrollView` prior **iOS 10**. The drift disappears when using `refreshControl`. See [SO 29791995](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43288926/218152) and [GitHub SO-29791995](https://github.com/SwiftArchitect/SO-29791995) demo

Comment: I have found a solution for this problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/55594743/1296280

Answer (score 12):

Remember that your tableview is just a subclass of UIScrollView. In your controller, implement `scrollViewDidScroll` method and call `-beginRefreshing` on your UIRefreshControl like below.

But the animation of the UIRefreshControl while going to refreshing state wont be as smooth as you would expect. But it works.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y < -98 && ![self.refresher isRefreshing]) {
        [self.refresher beginRefreshing];
        //do all the work
        [self.refresher endRefreshing];
    }
}
```

Comment: Mind you it is better to put it inside ScrollViewDidEndDragging:

Comment: I have found a solution for this problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/55594743/1296280

Answer (score 10):

The way you can adjust how far you have to pull is by altering the height of the `UITableView`.  `UIRefreshControl` adjusts its maximum distortion height proportionally to the height of the tableView.  If you can't change the height of the tableView, then please [file a bug](https://bugreport.apple.com) with the details of your situation and it will hopefully be addressed in a future iOS release.

Also, have you tried pulling down more quickly?

Comment: Adjusting the height of a tableview appears to have no effect at all.

Comment: @cannyboy that's very interesting.  Please file a bug with the details.  Thanks! :)

Comment: yep tableview height does not the change "maximum distortion height proportionally to the height of the tableView", I filed a bug

Comment: @ugiflezet there's no property for that; `UIRefreshControl` is supposed to be taking that in to account itself.  What was the # of the bug you filed?

Comment: @DaveDeLong yes i understand there is no such field exposed :), bug id: 12630914 , i also attached a small project demonstrating the issue

Comment: I have found a solution for this problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/55594743/1296280

Comment: @DaveDeLong seems the bug's still there. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40461168

Answer (score 0):

if your `contentsize`has the height is not enough to pull down, you might need to enable its vertical by using `self.collectionView.alwaysBounceVertical = YES;`