# UIRefreshControl is not worling in landscape mode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, uirefreshcontrol

**My working Code :**

```
-(void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
{
    if (self.collectionView.contentOffset.y < -80 && ![self.pullDownRefreshControl isRefreshing])
    {
        [self.pullDownRefreshControl beginRefreshing];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this SO Question : [UIRefreshControl in Landscape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12710755/uirefreshcontrol-in-landscape?rq=1) , It's a Bug (see the Comments of **Dave DeLong**'s Answer), however you can try the Answers given in the Question.