# UITableView dragging distance with UIRefreshControl

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, refresh, uirefreshcontrol

I'm having some trouble on implementing a UIRefreshControl on a UITableView.

Everything is working fine except the fact that I have to scroll something like 80% of the screen for the UIRefreshControl to get triggered. Sometimes I'm not even able to trigger it since there is a tab bar on the bottom of the screen, which cancels the scrolling movement when the finger reaches it.

I've looked at other apps, namely Apple's 'Mail', where the UIRefreshControl is triggered after scrolling only 30% of the screen.

What am I missing? Really need help on this one!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and it's quite possible that's the same cause for you.
For me happens that I hided the scroll indicator making me unable to see the obvious cause of the problem: the `UIScrollView`'s height is much greater than its `superView`...

Double check your `UIScrollView`'s height because the "dragging distance" it's just a percentage of that height. Same goes for `UITableView` too, since it's a child class of `UIScrollView`.

**EDIT:**
Seems that this isn't the only way to reproduce this problem, since the required drag distance to trigger the refresher is calculated in a buggy way. Refer to [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12710755/uirefreshcontrol-in-landscape) for more info.

But in general it will happen if your `UIScrollView`'s height is different than his parent container (e.g the screen itself).

Comment: `UIScrollView` support for `UIRefreshControl` starts at iOS 10. Prior that, you had a severe drift. See [SO 29791995](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43288926/218152)

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to not use UIRefreshControl and just utilize scrollViewDidScroll (or tableViewDidScroll if a tableView) on handle your refresh accordingly since UIRefreshControl can't be modified.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if ((scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.frame.size.height) >=    scrollView.contentSize.height)
    {
        // Refresh from here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, however I believe UIRefreshControl exists to be used and 'Mail'uses it. I've realised that in my app the UITableView scrolling distance compared to the finger swipe is much shorter than it is with 'Mail', i.e., for the same finger swipe distance, the 'Mail' UITableView scrolls much more than my App's UITableViews. I wonder why...

Answer (score 0):

After some extensive testing and playing around with UIKit I have come to a conclusion.

## TL;DR

`UIRefreshControl` isn't smart enough. To fix add this code in `viewDidAppear` or `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

```swift
let refreshControl = scrollView.refreshControl
scrollView.refreshControl = nil
scrollView.refreshControl = refreshControl
```

## Test setup

Single `UIViewController` in a Storyboard with a `UIView` as its `view` which in turn has a `UIScrollView` as only subview which in turn has a single `UIView` as subview with `top,right,bottom,left,width,height` constraints equal to `superview`. The viewController has freeform size with `1200p` height.

In the subclass of the `UIViewController` a `UIRefreshControl` is added by setting the `UIScrollView#refreshControl` to a new `UIRefreshControl` inside `viewDidLoad`.

When running the application in an `iPhone X simulator` and dragging the scrollView to perform a "Pull to refresh" one must drag considerably longer to make the refreshControl animating and send its notification it was pulled down.

## The problem

One of my hypotheses was that the `UIRefreshControl` gets its `dragging distance` set once it is added to the scrollView and since `AutoLayout` hasen't updated the root view's subviews at `viewDidLoad` the scrollView has a height of `1180.0p` instead of the correct `768.0p` thus the refreshControl's `dragging distance` would be calculated for the height `1180.0p` instead of `768.0p` and thus become much longer than expected when running the app.

## The solution

By updating the scrollView's refreshControl after the correct size for the scrollView has been set the correct dragging distance is calculated.

This update has to occur in a function where the correct size of the scrollView has been calculated, for example `viewDidAppear` and `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

```swift
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    
    let refreshControl = scrollView.refreshControl
    scrollView.refreshControl = nil
    scrollView.refreshControl = refreshControl
}
```