# swift pull to refresh

Tags: ios, swift, uirefreshcontrol

i have my `refreshcontroller` with a `scrollview`..

```
  self.refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
        self.refreshControl.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Frissítéshez húzzad! :)")
        self.refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: "refresh:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
        self.scrollView.addSubview(refreshControl)

func refresh(sender:AnyObject)
    {

//my refresh code here..

            self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
    }
```

I'm adding as a `subview` to a `scrollView`. It's working when the page content is `overflowing` the screen. but the issue arise  when i haven't received much data and it's not `overflowing`, the `pull and refresh` function is not working. :(

I'm not using `tableview`.

Can anybody help me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
self.scrollView.scrollEnabled = true
self.scrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = true
```

> var alwaysBounceVertical: Bool // default NO. if YES and bounces is YES, even if content is smaller than bounds, allow drag vertically

Answer (score 11):

## iOS 10 Update

`alwaysBounceVertical` is not entirely true, and `refreshControl` has been introduced:

1. **All iOS versions:** `bounces` is always required if `contentSize` is smaller than `frame`
2. **Pre iOS 10 versions:** `alwaysBounceVertical` is also required for small content
3. **iOS 10+:** notify the `UIScrollView` of the existence of a `UIRefreshControl` using `refreshControl`

### - iOS 10

`UIRefreshControl` is now supported by `UIScrollView`, using `refreshControl` just like `UITableView` in previous OS.
This means that the drag & pull down experience, is flawless, without drift.
*Follow the tap + drag on the white arrow in the animation below: they stay in sync*

[image: iOS 10]

[↻ replay animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjfgE.gif)

### - iOS 9 and earlier

You can add a `UIRefreshControl` manually to a `UIScrollView`, but that view has no awareness of such an element, and the pull to refresh tends to drift.
*Notice how much harder it is to pull to refresh on the animation below: scrolling of the white arrow drifts, and requires a much greater distance to trigger the control*

[image: iOS 9]

[↻ replay animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbGRI.gif)

---

Bypass `refreshControl` OS discrepancies with this scroll view `extension`:

```
var _refreshControl : UIRefreshControl? {
    get {
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            return refreshControl
        } else {
            return subviews.first(where: { (view: UIView) -> Bool in
                view is UIRefreshControl
            }) as? UIRefreshControl
        }
    }

    set {
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            refreshControl = newValue
        } else {
            // Unique instance of UIRefreshControl added to subviews
            if let oldValue = _refreshControl {
                oldValue.removeFromSuperview()
            }
            if let newValue = newValue {
                insertSubview(newValue, at: 0)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

► Find this solution on [GitHub](https://github.com/SwiftArchitect/SO-29791995).

Comment: The `return refreshControl` line (iOS 10) called the getter again, recursively. I had to rename `_refreshControl` to something else like `customRefresh`.

Comment: I want to disable the collection view bouncing effect and enable the refreshcontrol. How can i do that ?

Answer (score 9):

**Yes** We can use refresh control to UIScrollView, UITableview, UicollectionVIew..

Here is the code for **PULL TO REFRESH**,

```
var refreshControl: UIRefreshControl!
override func viewDidLoad()  {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    scrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = true
    scrollView.bounces  = true
    refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didPullToRefresh), for: .valueChanged)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(refreshControl)
 }

@objc func didPullToRefresh() {

   print("Refersh")

  // For End refrshing
  refreshControl?.endRefreshing()  


 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This UIRefreshControl is not supposed to work for UIScrollView. It is supposed to be linked with a table through an associated table view controller object.

> Note: Because the refresh control is specifically designed for use in a table view that's managed by a table view controller, using it in a different context can result in undefined behavior.

[UIRefreshControl Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIRefreshControl_class/)

Comment: Per the cited documentation, three years later, it looks like ScrollViews are now supported. (I confirmed it with a test).