# How to disable collectionview bouncing effect without affecting refresh control functionality?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uirefreshcontrol

I want to stop collection bouncing effect as well i want do pull to refresh .

```
    collectionView.alwaysBounceHorizontal = false
    collectionView.alwaysBounceVertical = true
    collectionView.isDirectionalLockEnabled = true
    collectionView.isScrollEnabled = true
    collectionView.bounces =  false
```

How to enable pull to refresh without bouncing effect in collection view?

Answer (score 0):

You can add UIRefreshControl and add an action method.

```
  let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
  refreshControl.tintColor = .blue
  refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refresh), for: .valueChanged)
  collectionView.addSubview(refreshControl)
  collectionView.alwaysBounceVertical = true
```

Comment: these things had been done but when i m setting collectionView.bounces = false , i am not able to pull down to refresh the collectionView.

Comment: Yes, You need to set bounce = true otherwise you can't add pull to refresh functionality.

Comment: Look at this link might be helpful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29791995/swift-pull-to-refresh

Comment: yes @rushabh thanks but i don't need bouncing effect in collection view. it is looking weird when i am using this custom layout

Comment: Kindly check out the link the layout which i am using for this i want to stop bouncing effect in collection view https://www.brightec.co.uk/ideas/uicollectionview-using-horizontal-and-vertical-scrolling-sticky-rows-and-columns