# Is it possible to change the sensitivity/pull distance of a UIRefreshControl?

Tags: ios, ios7

I have a `UITableView` displaying a table of data with a somewhat large `contentInset` value.  As a result, the user cannot trigger the `UIRefreshControl` because it expects them to scroll too far.

Basically, I'm wondering if it's possible to make UIRefreshControl adjust for `contentInset` values.

Edit: This question is mostly about curiosity, so I removed the extra details and rephrased the question to be more direct.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking why do you need to increase the height to double the screen height to force the preload of cells?

Comment: There are definitely better ways to do it (this was a temporary solution), but I was experiencing lag when scrolling down as it tried to render the upcoming rows.

Comment: See [question 12710755](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12771854/218152)

Answer (score 3):

I think you're going about this a bit wrong. If you've encountered this issue because of the mechanism you've created to preload cells, you should think of a different approach for preloading them. If there's any content to be rendered / loaded / downloaded, you could be doing this in a background thread and leave a minimal amount of work for `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. If you insist on keeping this implementation, I'd suggest looking up a [custom refresh control](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=refresh) as there is no way to customize the build in `UIRefreshControl` in terms of content offset for refresh (AKA sensitivity). I believe this is ultimately a good thing - there should be consistent user experience across apps running on iOS which use a refresh control.

Comment: agree. it's a bad move to have your own, slightly odd refresh behavior. just do the extra work and create a more robust preload solution

Comment: How can this answer get upvotes?
This is not in any way related to the question.
Reading the question the issue is not related to a mechanism to preload cell but is due to an inset which i assume is because there is custom content before any cell is loaded.

Comment: The question was edited since my answer was written. The answer got upvotes because it was probably good enough at the time.